# How do i notify iphone app when user cancel SSO process?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an issue with SSO facebook in my iphone app. I have searched but no userful result for me.
My app have two functions: login/sigup using facebook.
My problem is how do i notify my app that user cancel SSO? the steps follow describe for it:

1. User click on "Connect using facebook", then app switch user to Facebook app.
2. When facebook validation process not done, user press Home button (on his device) and go back my app.
   --> How to notify my app what happen here. i have found in Facebook SDK but no mentions for it.

Thank for reading.
GE.

Comment: for SSO implementation you save your facebook key in NSUserDefault (i guess because it is internal Facebook)

Comment: I found the reason for it, the reason is unthinkable.

That is before alow Facebook dialog show i show an alert confirm to user. I using method clickedButtonAtIndex of UIAlertViewDelegate to handle user's option. When user chooses "OK" facebook dialog will show, but alert view will dismiss after it so it dismiss facebook dialog also.

The solution is using didDismissWithButtonIndex method to call Facebook dialog show after alert dismiss.


--------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

For SSO implementation you save your facebook key in `NSUserDefault` (I guess because it is internal Facebook or cookies of www.facebook.com exist or not.)

So when you launch your app please check in callback method `applicationDidBecomeActive`  that
your `NSUserDefault` or Cookie exist or not  and show popup accordingly.

Comment: Thank for your quickly answer, i'll try it.